# How to install Grails on Linux Ubuntu LTS?

Tags: grails, ubuntu

I have `Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`. I wanted to install Grails and I have found informations on how to install it on `Ubuntu 14.04 VPS` [here](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-and-set-up-java-grails-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-linux-vps/). So I am a little confused.

- What are the difference between the two versions, `LTS` and `VPS`?
- Does it matter if I do not have `VPS` version?
- Can I install Grails on my Ubuntu? If yes, how?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A very simple way on Linux/Unix OS is to use the [GVM Tool](http://gvmtool.net/).

After installing the GVM tools you simply run

```
$ gvm install grails 2.4.3
```

in order to install Grails 2.4.3

**UPDATE:** Meanwhile gvm was renamed to sdkman.

Install [sdkman](http://sdkman.io/)

```
$ curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

In order you want to continue working in the same terminal window execute

```
$ source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

To install the latest version of Grails simply run

```
$ sdk install grails
```

or if need a specific version you can run

```
$ sdk install grails 2.4.3
```

Answer (score 8):

You may try these steps. But this is just a guess, am not much sure about LTS and VPS

- download `grails-{desired version}` zip file
- extract it into any folder.
- edit `.bashrc` in home folder such that

  `JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java/jdk1.6.0_25-64/`

  `export JAVA_HOME PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH export PATH`

  `export GRAILS_HOME=/path/to/grails/grails-2.4.2/`

  `export PATH="$PATH:$GRAILS_HOME/bin"`
- try to run `grails` command in terminal

Comment: I think your answer is good too, but I have installed it using [gvmtool](http://gvmtool.net/) (+1)

Answer (score 1):

`VPS` stands for *Virtual Private Server* in general (no special Ubuntu version) and `LTS` for *Long Time Support* added to a version number of Ubuntu to annotate a longer livetime (e.g. making this versions more suitable for servers).  So these letters have not much influence on your way of installing Grails. The instructions there (installing JDK from OS and using [sdkman](http://sdkman.io/install.html) (formerly GVM)) are sound advice to run Grails.

Comment: I have upvoted this answer because it is also answering about VPS version; why have you downvoted it? Please comment!